# Can't hear any sound with headphones in windows, but can in ubuntu

Tags: windows-7, audio, headphones

I have a (Dual booted) Dell Inspiron N5110 with `IDT High Definition Audio CODEC` and Windows 7.

In Windows 7, I can hear sound from the speakers, but when I plug headphones in, I can't hear anything through either playback device.

In Ubuntu, I can hear sound from the speakers, and when I plug headphones in I can hear the sound through the headphones. This is what I want to happen in Windows 7.

I have tried using the test function on both the "Headphones / Speakers" and the "Communication Headphones" when I have headphones plugged in (neither work). When I click the sound icon in my system tray when I have headphones plugged in, I can see the green line moving up and down when sound is playing, but I can't hear a thing.

This is what my sound window looks like in windows 7:

[image: Sound dialog Windows 7]

Comment: What happens if you click the bottom device, then press Set Default? In theory that should fix the issue. Also, reboot the system after that or reopen the program that uses the audio device so it will be set to the correct one. (may not always work, which is why I suggest to reboot)

Comment: @LPChip When I Right Click -> Set as default, nothing happens. I can right click -> set as default communications device and that changes it - no sound though. I have also tried right click -> test on both of them and I can't hear anything.

Comment: You must set the Communications Headphones as default, notice the check mark, then reboot the system, so every audio device goes through that.

Comment: @LPChip I can't set them as the default. I have set them as the default communications device, restarted, and still no luck. It was working before without the communications headphones set as the default device. Imgur link of what it now looks like: https://i.imgur.com/pMJNWdk.png

Comment: if you cannot set them as the default (not communication device) then thats where things aren't working. Try plugging the device in a different USB port, preferably not through a hub, and see if you can set it as default now.

Comment: @LPChip I don't have any headphones that plug into a USB port. Both my headphones and speakers were working fine before even without the `communications headphones` as the default device. I don't think that I have ever been able to set them as the default device.